# nonlinear integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

I have a non-linear integral equation that I'd like to solve with Mathematica:
[image]

```
g[y_] := y^2;
h[y_] := y^2/2 + c;
func=(g[y] f[y]/Sqrt[h[y]^2 + f[y]^2]);
```

Comment: It would be important to know if numerical solution is fine, or if you're attempting to find something analytically. I guess the latter, or do you have specific values for `c`?

Answer (score 3):

You should take the derivative with respect to $x$ of both sides. Then you obtain the differential equation
$$ f'(x) = \frac{g(x) f(x)}{\sqrt{h(x)^2+f(x)^2}}$$ and $f(0)=0$.
The latter can be solved using

```
g[x_] := x^2;
h[x_] := x^2/2 + c;
DSolve[{f'[x] == g[x] f[x]/Sqrt[h[x]^2 + f[x]^2], f[0]==0}, f[x], x]
```

It turns out that Mathematica is not able to solve the resulting differential equation.

Looking at the numerical solution (setting a value for $c$ and replacing DSolve by NDSolve), I believe that the (only) solution to your problem is
$$ f(x) \equiv 0.$$

Comment: By repeated differentiation, it is clear that `f` has zero derivatives of all orders at 0

Comment: @mikado: interesting observation. Still there could be a solution that is not analytic as $x=0$...